# SQL request with join from 2 tables ... what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: select, group-by

Most probably i'm doing something wrong (i'm not sql prof), but ..

I got 2 tables, 1st with users (chips), 2nd with entries, when the person logged in (date_in/time_in) and logged out (date_out/time_out).. Logged out can be NULL, as the person still can be not logged out yet.

I want to keep the list of every person, even if he wasn't logged in that day.

Problem is, if person got multiple entries in a day ...
(of course, `GROUP BY chips.assigned_to` cannot be used to show multiple entries)

I have written following request:
(some of the selects are for testing purposes already)

```
SELECT 
    chips.id as user_id,
    chips_inout.id as row_id,
    assigned_to,
    chips.chip_id,
    chips_inout.date_in as date_in,
    chips_inout.date_out as date_out,
    TIME_FORMAT(chips_inout.date_in, '%H:%i:%s') as time_in,
    TIME_FORMAT(chips_inout.date_out, '%H:%i:%s') as time_out,
    TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(chips_inout.date_out, chips_inout.date_in),'%H:%i:%s') AS totaltime,
    TIME_FORMAT(SUM(TIMEDIFF(chips_inout.date_out, chips_inout.date_in)),'%H:%i:%s') AS totaltime_daysum
FROM chips
LEFT JOIN
    chips_inout
    ON
    chips.chip_id = chips_inout.chip_id
    AND
    chips.chip_text = chips_inout.chip_text
    AND
    DATE(chips_inout.date_in) = '2024-01-22'
GROUP BY 
    chips.assigned_to
ORDER BY 
    chips.assigned_to, chips_inout.date_in
```

which will return:

[out1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLrrN.png)

If i will use `GROUP BY row_id` for example, will do the trick and will show multiple entries of the day, but of course will group rows with NULL result, what will cause show of 1 NULL line only.

[out2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhTK4.jpg)

From my point of view, easiest way should be to remove `GROUP BY ....` completly and my world should be all pink and nice, but this is the result:

[out3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seCuX.jpg)

All the time, returning 1 row only ......

What the hell i'm doing wrong? :)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to group on `user_id`, I think. As for the last query: when you use an aggregate with no grouping then the entire set is the group. Naturally you only get a single row.

Comment: shqwnt00 .... group on user_id will be the same as assigned_to .... :/

Comment: Are you wanting a running total? I'm not clear what's broken.

Comment: @shawnt00 what i want is to return table as result OUT1, but want to include each entry and exit of each person in separate row (as result OUT2). Must keep persons without entry/exit in the same time ...

Comment: Remove `group by` and use `TIME_FORMAT(SUM(TIMEDIFF(chips_inout.date_out, chips_inout.date_in)) over (partition by user_id), '%H:%i:%s') AS totaltime_daysum`?

Comment: @shawnt00 ... did the trick, master! Thank you a lot... I have to take a look and study a bit, what "over" and "partition by" is ...

Comment: @shawnt00 Ok, another problem, TIME_FORMAT and SUM of TIMEDIFF cannot be used, because when calculating SUM of 10:30:00 and 00:40:00, SUM will return 107000 / 10:70:00. what will cause #1292 error/warning and return NULL ... if i will use TIMESTAMPDIFF, TIME_FORMAT is not able to handle seconds, or minutes value .... however, different story, not to actual question. your "over partition by" window helped a lot. Thank you again.

Comment: @shawnt00 /// solved, nevermind :))
'''TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(chips_inout.date_out, chips_inout.date_in))) over (partition by user_id)), '%H:%i:%s') AS totaltime_daysum'''

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I think you're on MySQL and I don't know those time functions too well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove group by and use TIME_FORMAT(SUM(TIMEDIFF(chips_inout.date_out, chips_inout.date_in)) over (partition by user_id), '%H:%i:%s') AS totaltime_daysum

shawnt00

Solved...